# need help understanding new chrome 116 update with the new "LayoutFlexNewColumnAlgorithm" which makes my sites crash

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

Would like to know if anyone else having same issue and maybe have a fix or some information on the issue.

i'm shooting here in the air since i cannot find any information about the new flexbox column layout algorithm in chrome version 116 and up.

a site i'm working on became unusable and crashes because i use flex-flow: "column wrap" across many elements.

when i change the code to be flex-flow: "column nowrap" the site becomes reliable again but not aligned as i need.

Would be glad if anyone could bring some light into this issue.

Notes:

1. sorry if there is not enough information to help me.
2. no other changes in the codebase, just chrome update from 115 to 116 which caused the issue.

Please let me know if there is not enough information to help, ill try to scratch more.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] that illustrates the issue.

Comment: See https://twitter.com/Una/status/1668634249124282370